# How to build a Shinymanager and Brochure app with Golem

Tags: shiny, golem, shinymanager

I don't really have a repository to share as I am falling at the first hurdle sadly. I was wondering how to build an golem app that is both a Brochure and shinymanager one as I am hoping to create a login page for my app that leads to a menu page that can lead to multiple options of other pages.

I have tried wrapping the first page UI with secure_app but nothing happens when I hit 'log in'. I'm not quite sure how to determine what page the auth page goes to after logging in.

Just looking for a starting point to go off! Perhaps there is something else I can use other than Brochure to create a multi-page app with shinymanager log in?

Answer (score 0):

Please consider giving some form of code -- here is info on how to [write reprex](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) -- you are trying to execute, if you cannot provide a repo to work on.

Consider moving to the `polished` package for authentication. I have that working with the `brochure` package -- note it is still in development.

Comment: Attempting that now, I saw your other post on this and where you said:

sign_in_custom() is a function that returns a customized UI object from polished::sign_in_default() to create personal business webpages. I would recommend wrapping polished::sign_in_default() in a custom global function since you will need to define this on ever brochure::page() that you want to have protected behind polished auth.

Where do I put the custom ui function in order for it to be globally readable?

Comment: If you are building a package then you can put your `custom_sign_in()` function in the R folder and it will be globally available for you to use with `my_package::fct()`.  Your layout should be a package if youre using `golem` or `brochure`. If you do not have a package layout, then you must either initialize the function earlier in the script to when it is run (so it is viewable in the environment), or in another `.R` script that you then `source()` into your main script when you need the function. @JamesHopgood